# C# socket sending large file over than 2 GB

Tags: c#

I am trying to send the large file(greater than 2 GB) via Sockets in C#. I am sending it in chunks of 10 MB.
I will explain what is my approach. From client side, I will send the chunk and will wait for confirmation from server(if that chunk has been received or not). After receving confirmation, I will send another chunk and will again wait for confimation from server for that chunk. The loop will continue till all file data has been sent to. After successful sent operation of file, will close the connection from client side.

Client Side Code:

```
            try
        {
            DateTime startdate = DateTime.Now;
            string ori_text = btn_Send_Files.Text;
            btn_Send_Files.Text = "Do not click already sending...";
            btn_Send_Files.Refresh();
            IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses("localhost");
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5656);
            Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            clientSock.Connect(ipEnd);

            label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nConnected to:" + ipEnd.Address.ToString();
            label1.Refresh();

            string fileName = "CCCCCC.zip"; //It has size greater than 2 GB
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\CCCCCC\Downloads\";
            byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);

            label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nSending the file:" + fileName;
            label1.Refresh();
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath + fileName);
            
            int max = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
            long start = 0, bytesRead = 0;
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath + fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            max = max - (4 + fileNameByte.Length);
            byte[] tmpserver = new byte[100];

            using (fileStream)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (start < fi.Length)
                    {
                        i += 1;

                        label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nSending " + i.ToString() + " block of file:" + fileName;
                        label1.Refresh();

                        fileStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        if (max > (fi.Length - start))
                            max = Convert.ToInt32(fi.Length - start);

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[max];
                        byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + max];
                        byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);
                        fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
                        fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);

                        bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, max);
                        start += max;
                        buffer.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
                        clientSock.Send(clientData);
                        
                        Array.Clear(clientData, 0, clientData.Length);
                        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        Array.Clear(fileNameLen, 0, fileNameLen.Length);
                        Array.Clear(clientData, 0, clientData.Length);
                        clientData = null;
                        buffer = null;
                        fileNameLen = null;
                        GC.Collect();

                        label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nWaiting for confirmation of " + i.ToString() + " block of file:" + fileName;

                        int serverdata = clientSock.Receive(tmpserver);
                        if (serverdata == 0)
                        {
                            clientSock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                            clientSock.Close();
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nReceived confirmation for " + i.ToString() + " block of file:" + fileName;
                            label1.Refresh();
                        }
                    }
                }
               
            
            clientSock.Close();
            DateTime enddate = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan diff = startdate - enddate;
            label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nFile "+ fileName + " has been sent to:"+ ipEnd.Address.ToString();
            label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nTime Taken to sent the file(seconds):" + Math.Abs(diff.Seconds).ToString();
            label1.Refresh();
            btn_Send_Files.Text = ori_text;
            btn_Send_Files.Refresh();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File Sending fail." + ex.ToString());
        }
```

Server Side Code:

```
            try
        {
            label1.Text = label_text;
            label1.Refresh();
            string ori_btn_text = btn_Start_Server.Text;
            btn_Start_Server.Text = "Do not click already waiting...";
            btn_Start_Server.Refresh();
            label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nWaiting for client";
            label1.Refresh();
            string receivedPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Location"];
            Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();
            label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nServer Started and connected to client" + clientSock.LocalEndPoint + "\nWaiting for the file to receive";
            label1.Refresh();
            int max = 1024*1024*10;
            
            string logfile = receivedPath + "\\serverlog.log";
            if (File.Exists(logfile))
            {
                File.Delete(logfile);
            }

            FileStream fs = File.Create(logfile);
            byte[] serverdata = new byte[100];
            string fileName = "";
            int fileNameLen = 0, fileDataLen = 0;
            int i = 0;
            BinaryWriter bWrite = null;

            while (true)
                {
                    i += 1;
                    
                    byte[] clientData = new byte[max];

                    int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);
                    if (receivedBytesLen <= 0)
                        break;
                    
                    string tmp = "\nStarted:" + i;
                    fs.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tmp), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tmp).Length);
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
                        fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);
                        fileDataLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 4);
                        if (File.Exists(receivedPath + fileName))
                        {
                            File.Delete(receivedPath + fileName);
                        }
                        bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + fileName, FileMode.Create));
                        label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nReceiving File:" + fileName;                            
                    }

                    label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nReceived " + i.ToString() + " block of file:" + fileName;
                    label1.Refresh();
                    bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);
                    Array.Clear(clientData, 0, clientData.Length);
                    clientData = null;
                    GC.Collect();
            
                    clientSock.Send(serverdata);
                    label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nSent confirmation for " + i.ToString() + " block of file:" + fileName;
                    label1.Refresh();
                }
                if (bWrite != null)
                {
                    bWrite.Flush();
                    bWrite.Dispose();
                    bWrite.Close();
                }
                fs.Close();
                label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nFile has been received:" + fileName;
                label1.Refresh();
                MessageBox.Show("File has been received:" + fileName);
                btn_Start_Server.Text = ori_btn_text;
                btn_Start_Server.Refresh();            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File Receiving fail." + ex.ToString());
        }
```

It works fine on locally but over the network getting timeout exception on .receive() method on server side.

Comment: Any particular reason you are creating your own thing over using something that already exist and manage all that like let's say WCF ?

Comment: @Franck WCF is not appropriate for sending multigigabyte binaries. Heck, WCF is not appropriate for anything except _mental torture_. I swear, if I have to see another `ServiceBehavior` and `EndpointBehavior` and misconfigured `mex` in `web.config` I'm going to fill CORBA's offices with excessive amounts of dish-SOAP foam.

Comment: @Dai That is just your personal opinion. I never seen any problem or even complexity using WCF and nothing either particular using it to transfer data.

Comment: @Franck Please explain how a 2GB+ binary can be efficiently represented in a SOAP envelope.

Comment: @Dai Create a method with `Byte[]` parameter and send the data to the method. On the server write the bytes. 4-5 lines of code either side.

Comment: Why chunk it like that and not just do one big `FileStream.CopyTo`?

Comment: @Franck Giant 2GB+ arrays are a bad idea. That being said, it is possible using streams, but that gets really complex in WCF

Comment: @Franck That won't work because in .NET a `Byte[]` cannot exceed 2^31 elements, even on x64. Also, you'll consume ~4GB (or worse) of native/host memory due to how .NET marshals buffers between the OS and user-code. Knowing how to implement _streaming_ is an essential skill, and message/packet/envelope-oriented schemes like SOAP are completely inappropriate for this use-case for that very reason.

Comment: @Dai i have not noticed the greater than 2gb i tough it was less than 2gb. For greater size you use a stream parameter that works great up to 180~200 Gb file i don't know how far it works i never tried to push it further than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest you don't try to reinvent the wheel. There is no need to mess around with sockets and chunks of files.

Instead just open the file as a `FileStream` and copy it straight into a `NetworkStream`, which you can get using `TcpClient` (and `TcpListener` for the server).

You should also convert this code to be fully async.

```sql
public async void btn_Send_Files_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime startdate = DateTime.Now;
    try
    {
        string ori_text = btn_Send_Files.Text;
        btn_Send_Files.Text = "Do not click already sending...";
        btn_Send_Files.Enabled = false;

        await SendFileAsync();

        label1.Text += $"\nFile {fileName} has been sent to: {ipEnd.Address}\nTime Taken to sent the file(seconds):{Math.Abs(diff.Seconds)}";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File Sending fail." + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        DateTime enddate = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan diff = startdate - enddate;
        btn_Send_Files.Text = ori_text;
        btn_Send_Files.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private async Task SendFiles()
{
    string fileName = "CCCCCC.zip"; //It has size greater than 2 GB
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\CCCCCC\Downloads\";

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (var client = new TcpClient())
    {
        await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Any, 5656); // replace with remote IP
        label1.Text += $"\nConnected to:{client.Client.RemoteEndPoint}";
        label1.Refresh();
        using (var netStream = client.GetStream())
        {
            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(netStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Server-side code

```cs
public async void btn_Start_Server_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        label1.Text = label_text;
        string ori_btn_text = btn_Start_Server.Text;
        btn_Start_Server.Text = "Do not click already waiting...";
        btn_Start_Server.Enabled = false;
        label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nWaiting for client";
        label1.Refresh();

        await WaitForFile("SomeFilename");

        label1.Text = label1.Text + "\nFile has been received:" + fileName;
        MessageBox.Show("File has been received:" + fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File Receiving fail." + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        btn_Start_Server.Text = ori_btn_text;
        btn_Start_Server.Enabled = true;
   }
}


private Task WaitForFile(string fileName)
{
    string receivedPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Location"];
    var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5656);  // local IP to listen at, do not change
    try
    {
        listener.Start();

        using (var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync())
        using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(receivedPath, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            label1.Text = $"{label1.Text}\nServer Started and connected to client {client.Client.RemoteEndPoint}\nWaiting for the file to receive";
            label1.Refresh();

            await networkStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (listener.Active)
            listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Your existing code also passes the filename through the stream. I'm sure you will manage to adapt the above to do the same.

Also, if you want to show progress, it could get more complicated. You may need to write your own `FileStream`-derived class.

Comment: `DateTime startdate = DateTime.Now;` <-- That should be `UtcNow` instead of `Now` as the latter is subject to unpredictable changes due to local user settings changes and DST, but `UtcNow` is far more stable.

Comment: To be honest, `Stopwatch` would have been a better idea, but I just left in whatever OP did.

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you so much for this big help :). I can send files greater than 2 GB over the network.