# Splitting data in an ArraySegment<byte> to different Bytes[]

Tags: c#, arrays, out-of-memory, byte, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to make a C# program that allows 2 computers to send files between each other, the client is the sender, the server is the receiver. The problem now is that I'm using ArraySegment which uses a Byte[] variable which apparently supports only upto 2.147gb of data (max int value), and I have an idea of taking overloading data into another Byte[] variable. But I don't know how to do it, I also want to fix the issue of the program using said byte size for any file size (for example: a .txt file with a size of 24kb, in memory, the byte would be stored as 1,073,741,824kb  or  1.073gb) I want the byte[] to be the same size as the size of the data or atlease close to it.

Here's my code for this, also if there are any mistakes in my code or some optimizations could be made, I would be happy to know.

```
Buffer = new byte[1_073_741_824];

var BFR = new ArraySegment<byte>(Buffer, 0, Buffer); //[2_147_483_647]

var ReceivedByteLength = await Handler.ReceiveAsync(BFR, SocketFlags.None);

var BFR2 = new ArraySegment<byte>(Buffer, 0, ReceivedByteLength);

Console.WriteLine("File Request received from client.");
```

I tried researching and researching but could not really find anything related to my problem.

Comment: ArraySegment<T> constructor takes (T[], int32, int32) as operands and you're passing in (T[], int32, T[])... This won't compile.
You are correct in that this will always use 1GB of space regardless the size of the data passed in as that is how big you have declared your buffer.  Use a smaller buffer and then use streams for input and output and you will reduce your memory requirements.

Comment: Sounds like XY problems. Do you just want your program to receive large files?

Comment: What is `Handler`?  Is it a [`System.Net.Sockets.Socket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket)?

Comment: If you are using sockets, this might be helpful: [C# socket sending large file over than 2 GB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73035618).

Comment: Handler is the connection handler, here's the code for it:

`var Handler = await Server.AcceptAsync();`

Also do I want my program to just send large files, yes and no, I'm coding my program so that 2 or more computers could communicate, send files (big or small), etc.
Now also by the way, there is a small error in my post's code here's the actual change:

`var BFR = new ArraySegment<byte>(Buffer, 0, 1_073_741_824);`

Comment: So the program is just used to receive files, and you did it wrong. You should use a small buffer, then continuously receive and write the buffer to a stream or large buffer until all the transmission is complete.